# Do I have to register 100 ipads with UDID for in-house app?

Tags: ios, ipad, app-store, ipa

I created In-house application which we'll use in around 90 iPads (in-house).

I created .IPA file with profile which has only 2 registered devices with UDID.

application is working on 2 devise only which I registered with UDID.

Question is Do I have to Register all the 90 ipads with UDID and create .ipa file with that profile which has 90 ipads UDID.?

Or Is there any other way.?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you jailbreak the iPads, they will ignore code signing and you will be able to run the AdHoc app on them even if it doesn't include their UDIDs, even after the AdHoc profile expires.

Another option is to register for [Enterprise Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/).

Comment: We don't want jail-break any ipads. is this only solution.?

Comment: That or adding each UDID to your dev program. But it would make most sense if you just got Enterprise Developer Program which lets you distribute to any device.

Comment: I have already registered for Developer Program. How can I do that.?

Comment: I added a link to my answer. There is a different type of iOS Developer Program aimed specifically for situations like this, check it out.